# Is it secure to use keosd in an aws to let dapp/app server sign transaction?

Tags: transactions, eosjs, development, rpc, keosd

I would like to know if it is secure to run keosd on an aws locally as a hot-wallet, to let the server of a dapp send a transaction which should be signed to the aws. The server of the dapp would get back a signed transaction and would push this transaction per rpc-api to the eos-chain. Would an approach like this be secure from hacking and stuff?(so far i testet this approach locally)

I also think I have to run a node.js server on the aws with express installed or something like this, to be sure that only the dapp servers transaction are accepted. Or can i config the aws only to listend to specific ip and forward everything so it can be executed locally from keosd.

Are their maybe other secure methods, how the dapp/app server could sign transaction automatically without me sitting there with my ledger and confirm each transaction?

thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

This method would work, but it would only be as secure as your server, as you would need to keep the private key in plain text format, so anyone who could access the machine could sign transactions.

I asked a friend of mine who is a front end dev, he said:

> Have an oracle listen for on chain tx on irreversible block signal,
>   then it’s just a matter of executing a transaction signed by a key on
>   the receiver component
>
> Maybe you call it using c++ from the plugin or use a messaging system
>   to send a message to another component on another system which has the
>   keys

I hope that helps.